# linking c++ libraries on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, linker

I'm running the following command:

```
g++ -m32 testLogin.cpp  -L/root/c++/libs  -ldvrnetsdk -o testLoginO -lpthread  -lasound
```

the result:

```
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_trylock'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_readi'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_close'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_timedlock'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_drain'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_free'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_open'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_writei'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_any'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_prepare'
/root/c++/libs/libdvrnetsdk.so: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The first thing I did after this error was to include the libraries     -lpthread         -lasound,     I also worked on the parameters order but did not work. I appriciate any help.

Comment: Libraries after code & objects. `-pthread` not `-lpthread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With gcc, ordering of linking does matter.

So, try with different order.

```
 g++ -m32 testLogin.cpp  -L/root/c++/libs -lpthread -lasound -ldvrnetsdk -o testLoginO
```

See this question for order: [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

Alternatively, you can use start-group option.

```
gcc -m32 testLogin.cpp  -L/root/c++/libs -Wl,--start-group -lpthread -lasound -ldvrnetsdk -Wl,--end-group -o testLoginO
```

Edit: As you still get the error, use `nm` on strings on your library and check if the symbols for which linker error is given are in the library or not. Check for library version. You might be on 64-bit kernel.

Comment: tks! I used your second suggestion, with some modification: gcc -m32 -fuse-ld=bfd testLogin.cpp  -L/root/c++/libs -Wl,--start-group -pthread -lasound -ldvrnetsdk -lstdc++ -Wl,--end-group  -o testLoginO. It solved the pthread issue but I still have a undefined reference to `snd..." what I think is related to lasound library. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

did you try with just -pthread as  the linker flag...sometimes it does notw ork with -lpthread...

This should work

g++ -m32 testLogin.cpp  -L/root/c++/libs  -ldvrnetsdk  -pthread  -lasound